# Mobile menu does not work the first time a page loads

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have problem with my mobile menu on http://illmindz.pl
When I open this site the first time menu doesn't work but when I refresh site everything is good and work very well. Have you idea how fix it and solve this problem?

Comment: where are you adding your javascript? document on ready or window on load?

Comment: I don't know, this template was bought so this is the main problem.

Comment: Have you not approached the theme developer?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have an error ,

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at (index):1016
```

Just use ,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

And try to use jQuery instead of $